# ASP.NET Project: automatically update references on a DLL after it's recompiled

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET project references a DLL from another project.

Every time that DLL is recompiled, I have to do "Update Reference".
No big deal, but can this be automated somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can add both projects to the same solution, and create project reference instead of DLL reference. Then when you recompile your site it will automatically recompile the DLL project if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Is "another project" actually another solution? If they're in the same solution it should work automagically if you added a reference to the project instead of the .dll file.

Comment: There are in different solutions.

Comment: Like Alex Dn said, you should put them in the same solution, if only temporarily.

Comment: I think you can specify the path where you want the DLL to be copied after it's recompiled.

Comment: But when the projects are in the same solution, you can add a reference directly to the project, not the dll. In the end it uses the dll but it's a more dynamic connection to it.